# Amplitude extraction using STFT

Tags: python, dft, stft, time-frequency, scipy

I'm trying to recover amplitude/magnitude from an audio stream. I'm using FFT to go from time domain to frequency.

If I feed in a signal of known amplitude, the results I get from either windowing or using scipy.signal.stft are lower than what is being fed in.

I wonder if this is inherent to using a window, or if I'm just missing something.

```
sr = 44100
t = np.arange(sr) / float(sr)
sig = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 200 * t) #amp = 1, frequency = 200hz

A = np.fft.rfft(sig[:2048])
A = np.abs(A * 2/2048.0)
np.max(A)
#0.8720133060255314

(zf, zt, B) = signal.stft(sig[:2048], fs=sr, nperseg=2048)
B = np.abs(B)
np.max(B)
#0.4738186881461125
```

What I'd really like is to be able to combine the windowed results in B to get something close to the amplitude of the data, but a linear scale average does not seem to help. I'm not sure if its inherent or if I'm missing a scaling factor.

I did notice if I window the rfft I get pretty close to the results of stft, e.g.

```
win = np.hanning(2048)
A = np.fft.rfft(sig[:2048] * win)
np.max(np.abs(A * 1/win.sum()))
#0.4738443584361969
```

If I use a frequency picked to be the centre of an FFT bin (150.73), np.max(A) ~= 1.0 and np.max(B) ~= 0.5.

`scipy.signal.check_NOLA` is True for my parameters, and I can recover the original signal from complex B with istft.

I would appreciate any advice or guidance, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, STFT is fundamentally a *time-frequency* transform: convolutions with windowed complex sinusoids (i.e. bandpass filtering). You aren't going to "frequency", and "windowed Fourier transform" is just one perspective. And time-frequency is bound by Heisenberg: all parameters are imperfectly localized, including amplitude.

STFT is subject to the [one-integral inverse](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/76239/50076) (but not via `scipy` or `librosa` as their complex-valued transforms are  [flawed](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/1279)). What this means is, all STFT rows **sum** to the original input (if satisfiying one-integral's criteria), so if input amplitude is 1, the sum will reflect that value, not any of its parts. Moreover, specifically for amplitude, strict analyticity must hold (negative frequencies = 0), which isn't the case with STFT near DC and Nyquist; the narrower the window, the worse the problem.

`scipy` also internally normalizes according to `fs` to better compute some physical quantities, but that's just a distortion if we're seeking direct signal parameters. I don't know its implementation inside out so I'll just illustrate with `ssqueezepy` (which also lacks the flaw).

### Amplitude extraction criteria

1. **Strict analyticity**: `abs(fft(window))`, centered at frequency of interest, is 0 for negative frequencies.
2. **Analyticity scaling**: (relevant, Hilbert transform) double non-DC and non-Nyquist bins
3. **L1-normalized window, in time or frequency**: if in time, the peak of `|STFT|` will sometimes yield the exact amplitude; if in frequency, the sum of `|STFT|` will always yield the exact amplitude for a pure tone; both assume 1-3 hold.

   - **Frequency norm**, `window /= sum(abs(fft(window)))` (`window` padded to `n_fft`) |  Advantage: for a pure tone, the recovery is exact regardless of tone's frequency and `n_fft`. Disadvantage: it's useless for non-pure tones.
   - **Time norm**, `window /= sum(window)` | Advantage: works for any signal. Disadvantage: being exact requires `n_fft = inf` or signal spectrum matching those of the transform's peak frequencies; though "inexact" is still often very close

### Example

What I've done in code:

1. Handle 2 & 3
2. Avoid signal that's near DC or Nyquist; this handles 1
3. Use a window well-localized in time and frequency: if time fails, there's worse edge effects, if frequency fails, we lose analyticity over wider frequential intervals. This handles 1.
4. Use a window L1-normalized in time

Left is `|STFT|`, right is a temporal slice (rows) of its complex  values at time index 0, and printed below is the sum of the right plot:

```
sum(Sx[:, 0]) = (256-1.8782743491467817e-12j)
max(abs(Sx[:, 0])) / sum(window) = 1.0000000000000018
```

[image]

I used `hop_len=1` for maximum information, but greater `hop_len` is just its subset: `Sx_strided = Sx[:, ::hop_len]`.

### Alternative: synchrosqueezing

All the work is done for us:

[image]

though of course it's no silver bullet, see [article](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/71399/50076).

### Criteria demos

Above we've shown the complex `Sx`, but of interest is `abs(Sx)`, and they only matched by (simplifying) coincidence. Below,

- `Sx_adj` refers to having non-DC & non-Nyquist bins doubled
- `window_adj` refers to having `window` zero-padded to the row-wise length of the STFT convolution (i.e. time dimension), which provides the true frequency response of the window
- `window_adj_f` refers to having `window` zero-padded to length `n_fft`, which is how frequency norm is computed

#### 1. Everything's right

```
max(abs(x)) = 1
max(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) = 256
sum(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) = 7.18
max(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) / sum(window_adj) = 1 -- time norm
sum(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) / sum(abs(fft(window_adj_f))) = 1 -- freq norm
```

[image]

#### 2. Nonstationary (but single-component) case

```
max(abs(x)) = 1
max(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) = 257
sum(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) = 7.17
max(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) / sum(window_adj) = 0.998 -- time norm
sum(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) / sum(abs(fft(window_adj_f))) = 1 -- freq norm
```

The imperfection in time norm is due to (very small) boundary effects; freq norm just lucked out.

[image]

#### 3. Too close to Nyquist

```
max(abs(x)) = 1
max(abs(Sx_adj[:, 32])) = 133
sum(abs(Sx_adj[:, 32])) = 5.23
max(abs(Sx_adj[:, 32])) / sum(window_adj) = 0.729 -- time norm
sum(abs(Sx_adj[:, 32])) / sum(abs(fft(window_adj_f))) = 0.519 -- freq norm
```

Nothing works! **Analyticity**.

[image]

#### 4. Too close to DC

```
max(abs(x)) = 1
max(abs(Sx_adj[:, 32])) = 133
sum(abs(Sx_adj[:, 32])) = 5.23
max(abs(Sx_adj[:, 32])) / sum(window_adj) = 0.729 -- time norm
sum(abs(Sx_adj[:, 32])) / sum(abs(fft(window_adj_f))) = 0.519 -- freq norm
```

Same story.

[image]

#### 5. Multi-component intersection

```
max(abs(x)) = 2
max(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) = 142
sum(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) = 2.94
max(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) / sum(window_adj) = 0.41 -- time norm
sum(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) / sum(abs(fft(window_adj_f))) = 0.553 -- freq norm
```

[image]

#### 6. Insufficient `n_fft`

```
max(abs(x)) = 1
max(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) = 38.1
sum(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) = 15.9
max(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) / sum(window_adj) = 0.882 -- time norm
sum(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) / sum(abs(fft(window_adj_f))) = 1.06 -- freq norm
```

[image]

#### 7a. Excessive `hop_size`

```
max(abs(x)) = 1
max(abs(Sx_adj[:, 2])) = 78
sum(abs(Sx_adj[:, 2])) = 4.54
max(abs(Sx_adj[:, 2])) / sum(window_adj) = 0.226 -- time norm
sum(abs(Sx_adj[:, 2])) / sum(abs(fft(window_adj_f))) = 0.305 -- freq norm
```

This uses `hop_size=64`, with `len(x)=256`. All other examples use `hop_size=1`.

[image]

#### 7b. Minimal (best) `hop_size`

```
max(abs(x)) = 1
max(abs(Sx_adj[:, 96])) = 256
sum(abs(Sx_adj[:, 96])) = 18.6
max(abs(Sx_adj[:, 96])) / sum(window_adj) = 0.926 -- time norm
sum(abs(Sx_adj[:, 96])) / sum(abs(fft(window_adj_f))) = 1 -- freq norm
```

Note, from accuracy standpoint, lower `hop_size` is **always** better, and higher risks [aliasing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/80920/50076).

[image]

#### 8. Non-localized window

```
max(abs(x)) = 1
max(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) = 1.03e+03
sum(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) = 50.2
max(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) / sum(window_adj) = 0.928 -- time norm
sum(abs(Sx_adj[:, 128])) / sum(abs(fft(window_adj_f))) = 0.7 -- freq norm
```

Despite the sine being in nearly the ideal spot (which is f=64, right between DC and Nyquist), the results are still off because the window is `|noise|`, which has long tails in frequency and never achieves analyticity.

This is a frequency localization example, one can also be made for time.

[image]

### How's it work?

Unless already familiar, this should be read first: [Equivalence between "windowed Fourier transform" and STFT as convolutions/filtering](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/86938/50076).

- **Time norm**: dividing by `sum(window)` makes the filters peak at `1`. Recall, a filter at frequency `f` is just `fft(window)` shifted to `f`, and the DC bin of `fft(window)` is its peak, and DC is sum, so we're just cancelling that sum.

  - For a pure sine with frequency that exactly matches that tiled by STFT - `conv in time <=> mult in freq` - it's filter peaking at 1 multiplied by a unit impulse that peaks at the sine's amplitude. STFT takes the time result - which is `ifft` of this result, which is just a sine of the exact same amplitude and frequency.
  - For a pure sine with frequency that *doesn't* exactly match that tiled by STFT, no filter can perfectly align its peak of `1` with the sine's, hence the time norm fails.
  - For a single-component AM-FM signal, we favor the time domain perspective and observe that locally in time, it's the same story with same results.
- **Freq norm**: `n_fft=N` is convolving `fft(window)` with `fft(x)`, so dividing by `fft(window)` recovers the amplitude of `x`, *even if* the sine's freq doesn't exactly match STFT's tiling. `n_fft < N` is this convolution but aliased, so the result is no longer guaranteed. Since `n_fft = N` is both prohibitively expensive and completely unnecessary from feature standpoint, the frequency norm is pretty useless. But maybe it's still sufficiently accurate with `n_fft << N` in most cases, I've not checked.
- **Analyticity / "components"**: refer to [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/83257/50076).

#### Re: another answer

> The window gain is in most cases just the mean of the window, i.e. for a hanning window it's 0.5.

It's sum, not mean, as was shown. "Mean" implies that every point of the window is equally weighed, and that zero-padding the window changes STFT results, neither of which are true. It happens to be mean if we apply a specific normalization to STFT, but just because it cancels said norm.

#### Time-norm snippet

If `Sx = stft(x, window, ...)` and `x` is real-valued, for any config, we do

```py
Sx[1:-1] *= 2
Sx /= sum(window)
```

but again be sure the library doesn't do its own norms (e.g. scipy `fs`).

#### Answer Code

Available on [Github](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/StackExchangeAnswers/blob/main/SignalProcessing/Q86726%20-%20STFT%20-%20Amplitude%20extraction/main.py).

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed caused by windowing. The window obviously reduces the energy in every single frame but of course, due to the overlap there are twice as many frames.

The window gain is in most cases just the mean of the window, i.e. for a hanning window it's 0.5.

Comment: Maybe you meant sum.